# Install Linux via USB: Boot shows "Boot option restore"

Tags: linux, boot, grub, gpt

Question: How can I manually boot Linux on EFI systems with Grub?

Where I'm stuck:
I'm trying to install a custom kernel, root file system, and grub on an x64 computer. The USB stick has an equivalent installation script and boots, but when I attempt to install the eMMC on the x64 device it displays "Boot option restore". This is a reboot loop and I suspect it has something to do with the way I use Grub.

The images (not mine):

Main screen:

[image: Boot Option Restoration]

Available options:

[image: Boot Option Restored]

The (simplified) code:

```bash
#! /bin/bash
set -e

# Create GPT, partition 1, type BIOS boot, bootable flag
(echo -e "g\nn\n1\n\n+128M\nt\n4\nM\na\nM\nw\n") | fdisk /dev/mmcblk0
sleep 1
mkfs.vfat -N BOOT /dev/mmcblk0p1

# Create partition 2
(echo -e "n\n2\n\n\nY\nw\n") | fdisk /dev/mmcblk0
sleep 1
mkfs.ext4 -F -L ROOTFS /dev/mmcblk0p2

dd if=rootfs of=/dev/mmcblk0p2 conv=fsync
mount /dev/mmcblk0p2 /mnt
mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt/boot/efi
cp vmlinuz-custom /mnt/boot

chroot /mnt <<-EOF
        mount -t proc none /proc
        mount -t sysfs none /sys
        mount -t devtmpfs none /dev

        # This could be moved out of the chroot, but for is use this.
        update-initramfs -c -k custom

        umount /proc /sys /dev
EOF

grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --removable --recheck \
        --root-directory=/mnt \
        --efi-directory=/mnt/boot/efi \
        --boot-directory=/mnt/boot/efi/EFI \
        --bootloader-id=grub /dev/mmcblk0;

cat > /mnt/boot/efi/EFI/grub/grub.cfg <<-EOF
insmod gzio
insmod part_msdos
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
insmod normal
        
search.fs_label BOOT grub
search.fs_label ROOTFS rootfs
        
set prefix=/bogus  # Unavailable prefix (prefix required by Grub)
        
sleep 1
linux (\$rootfs)/boot/vmlinuz-custom root=UUID=$(blkid -o value -s UUID /dev/mmcblk0p2) i915.force_probe=* swiotlb=65536 module_blacklist="pinctrl_elkhartlake,dp83867"
initrd (\$rootfs)/boot/initrd.img-custom
boot
EOF
```

Already checked:

- UUIDs seem to be correct in Grub
- Installation script USB and EMMC are not the same but equivalent.
- Reset BIOS options to default settings
- All commands seem to execute correctly

Answer (score 1):

I can't remember fully, but I think it had something to do with writing Grub. Try to remove `--removable`. I used it to create the USB and it seems that using it twice seem not to play twice. Also try to remove `--recheck`.

Eventually I moved EFI-only where my kernel lives on the EFI partition. Through `efibootmgr` this is handled way better than Grub.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same blue screen, on a laptop with only Linux (no Windows). In your opinion, to which part of the system does that blue screen belong ? To the BIOS/UEFI (e.g., to the hardware), or to GRUB ?

What I did, in detail :

- I installed Debian on a SSD, but the ESP (EFI) partition on a USB stick (don't ask me why, it's just for some tests)
- At first boot everything went fine
- Then I removed the USB stick containing the ESP partition, and the laptop didn't boot. That was expected, given that it had no more ESP partition
- Then I plugged in again the USB stick, and it didn't boot either. That was unexpected.

After having read [this](https://wiki.debian.org/UEFI#Force_grub-efi_installation_to_the_removable_media_path), I started the process over, but this time I did `dpkg-reconfigure grub-efi-amd64` immediately after having Debian installed, and I answered yes to the question `Force extra installation to the EFI removable media path ?`.

Now it works, but with that extra blue screen :

- I remove the USB stick with the EFI partition, the laptop doesn't boot. Expected
- I plug the USB stick back in, now it boots, but shows the blue screen. If I select `Continue boot` it boots grub, and then Debian.

There is very few information on the web regarding that blue screen. Could you please share your thoughts about it ? Where does it come from, and why does it show ?

Comment: You should've posted is as a new question, but here some thoughts for you: by default on the ESP efi/boot/bootx64.efi is ran. On Debian systems, this runs efi/debian/grubx64.efi, which in turn finds and loads the kernel on your SSD. MOK is "machine owner key", thus not part of the BIOS. [This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/700857/uefigrub-boot-repair-keeps-adding-mokmanager-efi-to-boot-menu) has some information about MOK. When you have this problem, generally I think you need to reinstall Grub on your system due to faulty configuration. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. The blue screen seems to be part of Grub (see https://github.com/system76/firmware-open/issues/216, someone located the blue screen's text in Grub's source code). In my case all I had to do is select "Always continue boot" to get rid of that blue screen in the subsequent boots. Now my system behaves exactly like I want it to (a Debian distro with EFI and /boot partitions on a USB stick).